# SQL Server : Case Statement Sum

Tags: sql-server, sum, case, aggregate

I have the following **nested** query

```
select 
    sum(c.seats) as countPerfs, b.program, b.Prog_id
from        
    #LT_TEMP TableP
join        
    C_PROGRAM b on TableP.program_id = b.Prog_id
join        
    lt_data c on b.Program = c.program
join        
    LTR_BUDGET_REF a on TableP.program_id = a.ProgramID 
where       
    a.Participants = 'Y'
    and fyear = 2016
group by    
    b.Program, b.Prog_id
```

It returns output that looks like this:

```
program_id  season  program performance workshops   artists_sess    participants    audience
6           2016    LU:     NULL       NULL         NULL            NULL            NULL
7           2016    NC:     NULL       NULL         NULL            NULL            NULL
11          2016    AC:     NULL       NULL         NULL            NULL            NULL
12          2016    PD:     NULL       NULL         NULL            NULL            NULL
19          2016    MC:     NULL       NULL         NULL            NULL            NULL
```

Each program has different logic -- so If I want to calculate lets say participants. But when the program is MC we only want to return/sum certain data. But when the program Is LU we want to calculate all the data. and so on. 
How do I build that case statement.

for example if the program is MC we want to sum c.seats (from lt_data) but only where price is = 800. But if the program is LU we want to sum seats for all prices. if the program is PD we want to sum where the price is 800, 500 and 300. Things like that. Its a case by case basis but I'm not sure how to structure it.

Thanks in advance.

This is the full query

```
UPDATE  
        #LT_TEMP 
SET     
        program = h.Program,
        participants =  h.countPerfs
FROM        
(
                select sum(c.seats) as countPerfs, b.program, b.Prog_id
                from        #LT_TEMP TableP
                join        C_PROGRAM b on TableP.program_id = b.Prog_id
                join        lt_data c on b.Program = c.program
                join        LTR_BUDGET_REF a on TableP.program_id = a.ProgramID 
                where       a.Participants = 'Y'
                and         fyear = 2016
                group by    b.Program, b.Prog_id
) h 
where h.Prog_id = #LT_TEMP.program_id
and h.Prog_id not in (27, 28, 29)
```

Comment: Your output doesn't match with your query

Comment: A couple of `OUTER APPLY`s should do the trick.  Need more details on the case by case scenarios if you want actual code.

Comment: I've updated the query to add the full sql/update statement. But the issue is in the middle portion where I'm looking to update the sum - to a series of cases. Thanks.

Comment: @TTeeple please advise, on what details are needed.

Comment: From your question: "Its a case by case basis". We need to know what those cases are.

Comment: @TTeeple the cases are as follows scenario 1 - add all c.seats, scenario 2 - add all c.seats but only where price is equal to a specific value = 800 for example. and scenario 3 add all c.seats where price in (800, 500, 300) etc. The rest of the scenarios are variations of the above 3. Thanks.

Comment: Don't add details in comments; [edit] your question and add them there, where they can be seen (and properly formatted).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to do your aggregation and `CASE` logic at too high a level.  Try doing it in a subquery of lt_data grouped by program:

```
SELECT 
    c.Prog_id,
    fyear AS season,
    c.program, 
    SUM(l.seats) AS countPerfs
FROM        
    #LT_TEMP t JOIN        
    C_PROGRAM c ON 
    t.program_id = c.Prog_id JOIN        
    (SELECT
        fyear,
        program,
        SUM(CASE 
            WHEN program = 'mc:' AND price = 800 THEN seats 
            WHEN program = 'lu:' THEN seats
            WHEN program = 'pd:' and price in (300, 500, 800) then seats 
            ELSE seats
        END) AS calc
    FROM
        lt_data
    GROUP BY
        fyear, program) l ON 
    c.Program = l.program JOIN        
    LTR_BUDGET_REF b ON 
    TableP.program_id = b.ProgramID 
WHERE       
    b.Participants = 'Y'     AND 
    fyear = @fyear
GROUP BY  
    c.Prog_id,  
    fyear,
    c.Program
```

---

The relevant syntax example in MS's [definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.105).aspx) is:
Searched CASE expression:

```
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message after this `WHEN program = 'lu' THEN seats ELSE 0` that reads `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.` sorry that thats not very helpful

Comment: try it again with only one ELSE clause

Comment: i had comment out fyear also the system was complaining that its invalid, but the only way i got the case to work was to take out all the whens and else (just leaving the first line)

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?  [syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - 10.50.4000.0, SQL 2008 R2

Comment: updated link with that version's syntax definition.  You can also try returning the results of the subquery without the group by clause or SUM() function to see if it's returning the result you want.

Comment: I was able to add a few changes/update the code a bit and got it to work, only issue is that it has issues as part of an update statement. I can't do an aggregate (sum) in my update statement.

Comment: Sorry one other issue is that I want to specify the several specific cases and in the "else" scenario just have it count seats (without specifying pricing or any other detail) the bigger issue is that the logic doesn't work without adding a fyear parameter to each when statement and the fyear in the where clause wont work ... therefore my else with just seats doesn't work either

Comment: @YelizavetaYR, which table is fyear in?  You just need to join it to lt_data so you can limit by those rows.

Comment: fyear is in lt_data only -- it will end up being @fyear a temp variable as passed parameter to limit the data but only in lt_data what else would it be joined on?

Comment: you can return fyear the field in the inner query and apply the limit from the parameter value (where fyear = @fyear) in an outer query

Comment: i added `@fyear as fyear` in the inner query and added where `fyear = @fyear` in my where clause. However the when/sum statements didn't count fyear in the logic and calculated all the values for that program

Comment: the parameter goes in the outer query, not the inner.  the inner should return all seasons, not just the one matching the parameter.  the outer query limits the seasons by the parameter entered at runtime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120741/discussion-between-yelizavetayr-and-beth).